# How to find bus schedules from Jasper, Alberta

Tags: buses, greyhound, jasper

We will be visiting Jasper National Park but haven't yet decided where to go afterwards.  Besides renting a car or taking a train, we are considering taking a bus, and want to know what options we have for direct bus destinations.

Where can we find schedules for the Jasper bus station?  We know it's served by Greyhound (and possibly other companies) but we can't find a list of bus lines and departure times on the Greyhound website.  It does have a search interface that forces you to select a source, destination, and departure time, but this is almost useless if you don't already have a destination in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using Rome2Rio.com, I was able to ask for transportation from Jasper to Edmonton, Calgary, Vancouver and it identifies buses, both Greyhound and Brewsters.

The buses depart from the [Jasper Transit Station](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/ab/jasper/visit/depliants-brochures/jasper) at 607 Connaught Drive. There is regular Greyhound Bus service to and from Vancouver, BC and Edmonton, AB. If you want to get to Calgary, you transfer in Edmonton.

Jasper to Edmonton, [Greyhound 5020](http://bustracker.greyhound.ca/routes/5020/I/Kamloops_BC-Edmonton_AB/5020/05-31-2017), once daily 5 hours 37 minutes leaving at 6:45 am

Jasper to Vancouver [Greyhound 5409](http://extranet.greyhound.com/revsup/csked/pdf/730c.pdf), once daily 10 h 31 minutes, leaving at 5 am

Jasper to Calgary [Brewster](http://www.brewster.ca/transportation/brewster-banff-airport-express/) once daily 7 hours 30 minutes leaving at 1:45 pm

[Parks Canada](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/ab/jasper/visit/rendre-gethere) details how to get to Jasper National Park, located 192 miles west of Edmonton, 256 miles northwest of Calgary and 500 miles northeast of Vancouver.

Comment: Do you know for sure whether these are the only termini?

Comment: @Psychonaut the [railway and bus depot](https://www.pc.gc.ca/en/pn-np/ab/jasper/visit/depliants-brochures/jasper) are one and the same; it's the transit station. I've added the map to the answer.

Comment: That's not what I was asking.  I am asking whether, out of all the bus lines passing through Jasper, Edmonton, Vancouver, and Calgary are the only termini.  That is, are there other lines that end in other cities? I get the impression that you simply plugged a few major cities into a search engine.  I already discounted this sort of trial-and-error approach in my question as being unsuitable for finding an exhaustive list of destinations.

Comment: @Psychonaut YES and NO.. if you haven't been to Jasper, the town, it's very small and the station serves trains, buses, taxis etc.